# Avoiding Server-Side and Client-Side Validation Code Duplication in enterprise Web Applications

Tags: validation, web-applications, architecture

In order to design architecture for an enterprise application which has many input validation that must be done on both server and client, what is the best practice? What’s your opinion about having same JavaScript functions with known parameters and execute them on server and client simultaneously?
I have many validations must do same in client and server and i want to prevent code redundancy, the using of custom validation is not the point, the point is finding a way to preventing of duplicate code in client and server.
I want a right architecture not a technologically idea.

Answer (score 0):

The business logic of an enterprise application should be encapsulated on business layer.

The question is: are input validation business logic??

From my point of view some input validation ensure data consistency and should be busines logic. It's an architectural analysis.

Another consideration is the client. 
How many client do you have?? Web, android, ios... you have to implement client validation for each. But the business layer remains the same.

My answer is: you are the architect, take in mind application constraints and the above considerations and find a criteria to deploy the validation in server or client.

Comment: Thank you for your time, But i think your questions are answered before. My client is just Web Application and my validations are common business logic between UI layer(Web) and server.But the point is avoiding duplicate code in UI and server,and my idea is executing validation JS in server an client side same time.